# How to save SMS to inbox in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have an application which sends an SMS using the Blackberry MessageConnection api. I would like to be able to save the sent message to the Outbox/Inbox of the device, so the user can see what messages were sent.

Here's a snippet of the code that sends the message:

```
returnMessage.setAddress(msg.getAddress());
returnMessage.setPayloadText(_currentMessage.getText());
_messageConnection.send(returnMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/SMS-not-saving-in-outbox/m-p/456209/highlight/true#M90695) if you're not on a CDMA network and if you don't specify a port number in the address then the message should go to the sent folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working that way. It's currently sending to sms://+phone number, but no port, and yet it doesn't show up. And I'm not on CDMA. Thanks for the reply, though.